# He (did dance vs danced) on the stage

Tags: sentence-construction

> He did dance on the stage.
>
> He danced on the stage.

Is there any difference in these two sentences or they can be used interchangeably ?

Comment: Both of them describe the dance happening on stage in past, however the sentence with **did** is more emphatic. So, the usage will be according to whether or not one wants to emphasize.

Comment: Can we use did+any verb(first form) instead of second form of verb to emphasize ? E.g. He did eat instead of He ate.

Comment: Yes, we use "did" in an affirmative sentence precisely for the same effect (emphasis)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are quite different. I wouldn't say that they can be used interchangeably.

1. *He danced on the stage* - simply states a fact that **he danced**.
2. *He did dance on the stage* - can either state a countertruth to either a falsehood or a disbelief or emphasize the statement that **he danced**.

Let's assume someone is telling another person that some woman was afraid to sing at a yesterday's vocal contest, but a third person states that she in fact did. Here's the situation:

> - Person 1. *Yesterday she was invited on stage, but she was afraid to sing.*
> - Person 2. *So she didn't sing?*
> - Person 3. *I heard her sing yesterday.*
> - Person 2. *So did she sing or not?*
> - Person 1. *Not while I was there.*
> - Person 3. *She did sing later in the evening.*